# How is MongoDB's "$inc" called in a Loopback 4 repository?

Tags: mongodb, typescript, loopback

I'm attempting to do the following with Typescript and the loopback-connector-mongodb library, but get the error `Object literal may only specify known properties`.

```js
interface Foo {
  likes: number;
}

// increase likes with MongoDB's '$inc'
async increaseLikes(id: string): Promise<void> {
  await this.fooRepository.updateById(id, {"$inc": {likes: 1}})
}
```

[MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Typescript compilation error even though the code is valid *Javascript*.

The error can be suppressed with `// @ts-ignore`

[Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments)

```
interface Foo {
  likes: number;
}

// increase likes with MongoDB's '$inc'
async increaseLikes(id: string): Promise<void> {
  // error suppressed to allow use of MongoDB's extended operators
  // @ts-ignore
  await this.fooRepository.updateById(id, {$inc: {likes: 1}})
}
```

Comment: HI, thank you for your answer. I added the ignore tag and now get an other error. Did you happen to get the same one? `Unhandled error in PATCH /icons/count/5f14e97ad00d3506bff85a85: 500 MongoError: The dollar ($) prefixed field '$inc' in '$inc' is not valid for storage.` and I have set `allowExtenderOperators: true` in the `mongo.datasource.ts`

Comment: @chrisloughnane The error is new to me. Were you able to solve it?

Comment: +Winfred I did, another SOF member pointed me in the right direction. In my comment above I had `allowExtenderOperators` and it should have had 'd' instead of 'r' for `allowExtendedOperators`. As with many of these things the problem was between the kb and chair :) 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63023681/1265302